# Reading cv.VideoCapture(camera) returns (False,None) on Raspberry PI 4

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble with compiling this code from the OpenCV documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(cv.CAP_V4L)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS,40)
if not cap.isOpened():
 print("Cannot open camera")
 exit()
while cap.isOpened():
 # Capture frame-by-frame
     ret, frame = cap.read()
 # if frame is read correctly ret is True
     if not ret:
         print(frame)
         print("Problems reading frames")
         break
```

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 and the Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3. The camera itself works fine, as I'm able to take pictures and record videos using libcamera in the console. Here is my build information for OpenCV:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /build/opencv-EaEjAq/opencv-4.5.1+dfsg/contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-06-16T12:09:47Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.6-armmp armv7l
    CMake:                       3.18.4
    CMake generator:             Ninja
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/ninja
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:
      requested:                 DETECT

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 10.2.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/opencv-EaEjAq/opencv-4.5.1+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/opencv-EaEjAq/opencv-4.5.1+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/opencv-EaEjAq/opencv-4.5.1+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/opencv-EaEjAq/opencv-4.5.1+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/opencv-EaEjAq/opencv-4.5.1+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/opencv-EaEjAq/opencv-4.5.1+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -g  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform java line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab viz ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      sfm
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv gapi julia matlab ovis python2 ts
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               doxygen python javadoc
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.24)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.66.8)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 YES (ver 9.0.1)

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so (ver 62)
    WEBP:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   OpenJPEG (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libImath-2_5.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libIlmImf-2_5.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libIex-2_5.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libHalf-2_5.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libIlmThread-2_5.so (ver 2_5)
    GDAL:                        YES (/usr/lib/libgdal.so)
    GDCM:                        YES (3.0.8)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.6)
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.91.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.45.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.51.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.7.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   YES (1.18.4)
    PvAPI:                       NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
    gPhoto2:                     YES

  Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.3 interface 11103)

  Trace:                         YES (built-in)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.9)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprotobuf.so (3.12.4)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /usr/include/CL
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.9.2)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.9.so (ver 3.9.2)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.5)
    install path:                lib/python3.9/dist-packages

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3

  Java:                          
    ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.9)
    JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /usr
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I first checked if the camera itself was the problem, but it is working fine. Then I checked, if the problem was with the kernel and ran it in the terminal, which yields the same results. Similar questions led me to believe that ffmpeg being disabled was the problem, but in the build info it says that it is enabled.
So if you have any tips to solve this problem, they're greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace this `cap = cv.VideoCapture(cv.CAP_V4L)` with `cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)`